# Scroll to the right in excel formula entry field

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, user-interface

I can't believe this question hasn't been asked, but I can't find an answer anywhere on the webs, so:

There are lots of formula entry boxes scattered around in excel that are too darn small, and for some mysterious (to me) reason are not resizeable..  I run into them in selecting data for graphs, defining named ranges and, today, in trying to edit a custom formatting rule.

[image]

The formula shown extends for another few arguments to the right, one of which I want to edit.

I can click on the popout button, of course, but the popout isn't any better. 
[image]

If I put the cursor towards the end of the extry field and try to scroll right, excel inserts a cell reference based on which cell was selected before I entered the dialog.

[image]

The only way I know of to freely move around within this formula is to place the cursor in it, ctl-a to select all, and ctl-c to copy for pasting and editing in notepad++.  It works, but what a hassle!

So:  Is there a way to use the keyboard to scroll around within an inappropriately small formula entry field in Excel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just press <kbd>F2</kbd>. :)

You will see the indicator at the bottom-left corner of the screen change from ENTER to EDIT to indicate that you entered EDIT mode where the arrow keys will navigate the text field instead of inserting cell references.

Comment: Oh wow.......You have made me so happy.

Comment: @Adam Glad I could help! This really bothered me too before I figured out the F2 shortcut.