# Excel - Can one move the text-cursor in a range-input field using the keyboard?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard, input

This is a 'small' but extremely frustrating issue, and I would be very grateful if somebody could give me a hint:

Whenever one has to "select" data in Excel - f.e. to define a chart data range - there is a field into which one can type the range. Simultaneously, one can use the mouse to highlight the data directly in the sheet.

Using any of the cursor-keys, the selection changes (and the field-text updates).

However, this also makes editing the entry-field a living nightmare. If you mistype or want to insert some text at a different cursor position in the field, **you can not use the keyboard left/right keys** to move the text-cursor to a different position in the field.

[image]

Within seconds, the field becomes a tangled mess, like this example:

[image]

> ### Is there a way to move the *text cursor* in the input field with keystrokes?

Or, in other words: how can I get from the first to the second situation *without using the mouse* (just using the keyboard)?

[image: FROM] ==> 
[image: TO]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar question here:
[Scroll to the right in excel formula entry field](https://superuser.com/q/990871/722445)

Answer: while in the entry field, press <kbd>F2</kbd>; an indicator on the bottom left of Excel will change from "Enter" to "Edit". You'll be able to move around the field using the arrow keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Nearly a year in and I wouldn't have found it.